# Reading from assets gives null pointer

Tags: java, android, file-io, assets, android-context

I have a file in the `assets` folder that I want to access in a class I've named `StorageManager` (just a regular class, doesn't extend anything):

```
public class StorageManager {
    private Context context;

    public StorageManager(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open(filePath);
        String results = "";
        int data = is.read();
        while (data !=-1) {
            results += (char)data;
            data = is.read();
        }
        is.close();
        return results;
    }
}
```

I'm creating an instance of this class within a `ListFragment` and passing `getActivity()` as the context.

However when I make a call to `readFileAsString` with a valid `filePath` I get a `NullPointerException` for the line:

`AssetManager am = context.getAssets();`

I'm assuming that means the context is null. But why? How do I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

How its called:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, .....etc) {
        ...
        StorageManager storage = new StorageManager(getActivity());
        try{
            String filetext = readFileAsString("file");
        }catch(...)}
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: yes context is null how do you pass the constructor and from where?

Comment: show your valid filePath.

Comment: I have a ListFragment in a ViewPager, I call:

StorageManager storage = new StorageManager(getActivity());

 from within the class that extends ListFragment

Comment: call this.getAssets(); may be work

Comment: What is null actually?

Comment: @sunil I cant its called in a ListFragment not an Activity

Comment: Debug & check what getActivity() is giving you before you instantiate the class. Try StorageManager storage = new StorageManager(FragmentActivityName.this);

Comment: It’s always a good pattern to check constructor arguments intended to be stored into the instance for `null` to fail-fast on errors instead of getting exception at a far later time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getActivity().getBaseContext();